# jQuery val() does not set

Tags: jquery

```
    <div ... ondblclick="setEmail()">
    <script>
    function setEmail(){
      $('#email').val('tux');
    }
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="email"/>
```

This does not set the value of element "email".
What might the problem be?

EDIT

I edit{ed question, i am not trying to change a div's text, i am attempting to change an input's value.

There is a json and if i turn in the loop, the line works,

```
function setEmail(){
    $.each(obj,function(){
    if(){
    $('#email').val('tux');
    }
    });
}
```

Above code works, but i should not loop, it is unnecessary.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us all of your HTML. From what you've provided above it is hard to tell what might be happening.

Comment: Please set up a JS Fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery is loaded correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the function is being called? Also dblclick implementation seems patchy in earlier IE versions, what browser are you testing on?

Answer (score 1):

Div elements do not have a val, but only an html.
val is onlky available for INPUT elements

```
$('#email').html('tux');
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your div an ID and do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setEmail() {
        $('#email').val('tux');
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MyDivId').click(function () {
            setEmail();
        });
    });
</script>
```

this set the value of the input for me

Answer (score 0):

Your eventbinding is wrong:

you schould use onDblClick istead of ondblclick